# Overriding transitive version dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, dependency-management

What are the conditions to be met when using the `<properties></properties` tag to override a transitive dependency in maven? For example, in this sample github project (https://github.com/Richou/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) I want to override the version of slf4j-ext used in swagger-codegen by defining the required version inside `<properties>` tag in the parent pom. What are the conditions for that?

**NOTE**: I understand that `<dependencyManagement>` can be used for this purpose but I want to get better insight on version overriding and how the pom works.

Comment: I guess you cannot override properties of transitive dependencies, but I am really not sure.

Comment: You can only override the direct dependencies of your project by adding those dependencies to your project. This is also possible by adding a dependency directly to your project. The decision is made by the distance between your project and the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you need to define a transitive dependency by tagging to a specific version.

lets say:

1. your wished dependency needs a newer transitive dependency.
   In this case you have a issue with the newer dependency.
2. your wished dependency needs a older transitive dependency
   In this case you want to have your newer dependency to use or not at all
3. you need to upgrade a transitive dependency of a dependency itself?
   in this case exclude the dependency and add it as you own dependency

in the first case you can use dependency exclusion like explained here
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions

In the later case you need to verify if your transitive dependency will work or if you need also to exclude the transitive dependency.

to upgrade the

Comment: I am not looking for dependency exclusion. I need the the transitive dependency in my project but need to upgrade the version of that dependency only without changing the version of the base dependency. I also need a method other than `<dependencyManagement>` to do this hence why I specified using `<properties>`

Comment: still not fully clear. You can exclude the transitive dependency and add it as you own dependency. Added this also in the above answer.

Comment: Let me give you better context. I am asking about the option 2 in Workarounds and Fixes given in the following link [link](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot). I tried this in the github project given in the link in my question but it didn't work. I want to know why.

Comment: I think it might be helpful. https://andresalmiray.com/maven-dependencies-pop-quiz-results/